# Dropdownlist is not allowing new items added dynamically

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Expt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void Bttnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       DropDownList11.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);


    }
 }
```

In this when i add the item in dropdown list it shows an error:"Dropdown list does not allow multiple seelection"

But when i used to print the selected item It shows null exception error.

Comment: Also include the error it is giving you.

Comment: Without a bit of sample code we have no idea what the issue is.  Please add the code you are using AND indicate what error you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add new list items like that :

```
DropDownList11.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text, ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value)
   );
```

Because you're adding the ListItem that selected by the ListBox, it's `Selected` property is true. Then you get this exception.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But why not the drop down list print the seelected item.